# 20 pixels issue when using container inside container view controller iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ios6

I have base view controller embedded in UINavigationController consisting of two container views, the first container contains another Viewcontroller embedded in UINavigationController which further has another containerView. The issue I face is the second Container leaves 20 pixel gap. Also the whole rendering of the views is not as expected.

Attached sample project link https://www.dropbox.com/s/0le72fiofzizml2/Test.zip

Attached sample screen shot as well

[image]

Comment: are you using nibs or story boards or creating your views programmatically? Are you using the ios6/7 deltas? post some screenshots and code, so that its easier for anyone to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Using Autolayout and storyboards, so no possible deltas. Just simple storyboard connections and no code at all, only constraints